# how to increment index value of integer array

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to store value from datatbase table to array.but when I do,exception"object eferance not set instance of object " through please review my code.

**.cod Behinde**

```
   public DataSet showoption1()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from assessmenttest",con);

        SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adptr.Fill(ds,"test");

        int [] arr=new int[10];
        DataTable table=ds.Tables[0];
        for(int i=0;i<table.Rows.Count;i++  )
        {
test.Agree[i] =Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["option1"]);

    }
```

**Business logic layer class code:**

public class test{

public static int[] agree;

}

Comment: possibly test or test.agree not initialized...but why you using array?

Comment: Are you sure that `Rows[i]` contains the `'option1'`?  You might want to try a `foreach` statement instead on the items in a row to vcrify that you are getting what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

`test.agree` is `null`.

You need to put a new array in the field.

Answer (score 1):

Where exactly are you getting the error, on which array?  By the looks of it, it has to be on the agree[] one, which you never instantiate.

try

```
public static int[] agree =new int[10];
```

but I think you might want to make agree a list since you don't know how many you need

```
public static List<int> agree = new List<int>;
```

then usage

```
agree.Add(Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["option1"]);
```

and you can access it the same as an array

```
MessageBox.Show(agree[1].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate before adding values :

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from assessmenttest", con);

        SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adptr.Fill(ds, "test");

        int[] arr = new int[10];
        DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];
        test.agree = new int[table.Rows.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            test.agree[i] = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["option1"]);
        }
```